# Height of the slider according to the width of the screen

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I just [created a slider](http://www.jddemo.byethost10.com/) with bootstrap 3 and it works fine.

I want to like [this site](http://fr.wix.com/website-template/view/html/655?originUrl=http://fr.wix.com/website/templates/html/business-services/car-transportation/2&bookName=create-master-sort-211113&galleryDocIndex=1): i.e. the image is reduced height to the width of Register Main Menu.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Taken directly out of [normalize.css](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/)

**CSS:**

```
img {
  /* Remove border when inside `a` element in IE 8/9. */
  border: 0;
  /* Improve image quality when scaled in IE 7. */
  -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;

  /* Suppress the space beneath the baseline */
  /* vertical-align: bottom; */

  /* Responsive images */
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  /* Correct IE 8 not scaling image height when resized. */
  width: auto;
  width: auto\9;
}
```

Comment: Sorry but I do not really understand your answer. I must add this code in my class .carousel-inner > .item > img ?

Comment: Yes but I would recommend you add this as-is so every image is responsive and adjusts to browser sizing changes.  If you don't want other images to scale properly, then replace my `img {` with your `.carousel-inner img {` as you see fit for your situation

Comment: It does not work. The height is always 500 px according to browser width

Comment: You have to remove the `height` property if you want it to scale proportionally.

Comment: Ok but if I remove the images no longer appear!